# What is the correct type cast to avoid a compiler warning using SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY from winsvc.h

Tags: c, windows-services

When trying to set the SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY using the example at
[Creating Windows service without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699/creating-windows-service-without-visual-studio)
and compiling using the mingw32 cross-compiler on Fedora 14 I get a compiler warning.

The shortest I can make the sample is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsvc.h>

#define MY_SVC_NAME "My Service"

int cont_running = 1;

DWORD WINAPI ServiceHandlerProc(DWORD ControlCode, DWORD a, void *b, void *c)
{
  switch (ControlCode)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP : ;
      cont_running = 0;
    }

  return 0;

}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  int hServiceStatus;
  hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(MY_SVC_NAME, ServiceHandlerProc, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceStartTable[] =
  {
    { MY_SVC_NAME, ServiceMain },
    { 0, 0 }
  };

}
```

but the compiler is complaining about MY_SVC_NAME being the wrong type.

```
$ /usr/bin/i686-pc-mingw32-gcc -o /tmp/test ~/c/sample.c 
sample.c: In function 'main':
sample.c:31:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

I've tried assigning a variable and using type LPSTR LPWSTR char * and char [] and also tried casting the type within the curly braces, but its not working.

Looking at /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/winsvc.h I see its defined as

```
typedef struct _SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYA {
    LPSTR lpServiceName;
    LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA lpServiceProc;
} SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYA,*LPSERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYA;
typedef struct _SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW {
    LPWSTR lpServiceName;
    LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW lpServiceProc;
} SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW,*LPSERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW;
...
typedef SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY,*LPSERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY;
...
typedef SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYA SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY,*LPSERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY;
```

So surely using

```
LPSTR my_svc=MY_SVC_NAME;
  SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceStartTable[] =
  {
    { my_svc, ServiceMain },
    { 0, 0 }
  };
```

Should work ???

Sorry, another search revealed this example code at
[Windows Service C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734763/windows-service-c)

I changed my code to

```
  SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceStartTable[2];
  ServiceStartTable[0].lpServiceName = MY_SVC_NAME;
  ServiceStartTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;
  ServiceStartTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
  ServiceStartTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;
```

and now it compiles without warnings.

Comment: How is `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION` defined? I have a strong hunch it needs to return `int`, not `void`. Try changing your `ServiceMain` function to return `int` and dropping the cast.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, but the typedef does specify void.           
`   typedef void (WINAPI *LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA)(DWORD,LPSTR*);    typedef void (WINAPI *LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)(DWORD,LPWSTR*);    typedef LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION;    typedef LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION;   `

Comment: You missed a closing backtick in that comment; you still have time to edit it.

Comment: Yeah - I editted it a few times, even removing \n's but I guess its too long or too many other characters for back ticks to work correctly.

Comment: You just need to delete the space after the opening backtick and before the closing one (newlines are ignored in comments): `typedef void (WINAPI LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA)(DWORD,LPSTR); typedef void (WINAPI LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)(DWORD,LPWSTR); typedef LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION; typedef LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION;`

Answer (score 1):

This information is from the comments:

```
typedef void (WINAPI LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA)(DWORD,LPSTR);
typedef void (WINAPI LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)(DWORD,LPWSTR);
typedef LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION;
typedef LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION;
```

(Presumably only one of the latter two typedefs will be active.)

`LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION` is a typedef for a function returning `void` and taking two arguments of types `DWORD` and `LPSTR` or `LPWSTR`.  Your `ServiceMain` function returns `void` and takes *three* arguments of types `int`, `char**`, and `char**`.

Change the definition of `ServiceMain` function so it's compatible with `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION`.

Casting `ServiceMain` to `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION` will silence the compiler warning, but it *doesn't* solve the problem.  It will cause your function to be called *as if* it were declared correctly, with unpredictable results (undefined behavior).  All casts should be viewed with suspicion; if your compiler is warning you about a type mismatch, the best solution is usually to change your declarations so the types match, not to force the compiler to pretend that they're ok.

(Is there a typedef that's either `LPSTR` or `LPWSTR`, depending on the configuration?)